# Unable to connect to redis cluster with node client, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have spun up an AWS ElastiCache redis instance running in clustered mode, which currently has 1 shard and 2 nodes

In order to connect to it from my local machine I have opened up an SSH tunnel using my SSH config file

```yaml
Host myRedisTunnel
  HostName 1.2.3.4
  ...
  LocalForward 6378 5.6.7.8:6379
```

the tunnel works, I can connect to my VPC successfully

```sh
$ ssh myRedisTunnel
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1060-aws x86_64)
...
```

I can connect to the redis cluster locally via `redis-cli` after opening my tunnel and passing -c as an argument for clustered mode

```sh
$ redis-cli -c -h localhost -p 6378
localhost:6378> ping
PONG
```

but when I try to use `redis` for nodejs it wont connect, it just times out, am i missing some configuration settings, or is it physically impossible to connect to my remote redis via tunnel?

```js
const { createCluster } = require('redis')

const client = createCluster({
  rootNodes: [
    { url: 'redis://localhost:6378' }
  ]
})

await client.connect()
const res = await client.ping()
console.log({ res })
```

```sh
Error: Connection timeout
      at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:163:124)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:513:28)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
      at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:486:8)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

I have tried several nodejs clients for redis and all of them have timed out in the same way, so I know the issue has to either be that I have a config setting wrong in my nodejs redis client configuration - or it has something to do with only one of the redis ip addresses is accessible via tunnel, all the rest of the cluster would likely not be accessible unless i open tunnels for each one. Im just at a loss for how mock my production environment in development so i can write code.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you've pointed out, you'll need to create a tunnel for each node in the cluster
2. The clients are using the [`CLUSTER NODES`](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-nodes) command in order to discover all the nodes and the cluster, and this command will return the actual IPs and ports of the nodes, not the tunnels. You can use `ioredis` with ["NAT Mapping"](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#nat-mapping) to solve that.